# How to Insert a value where not exist in SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I want to insert values into my table only when values don't exist in the table.

```
 String CREATETABLE = "CREATE TABLE contacts ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                "name TEXT, "+
                "phone TEXT )";
```

Here is my code to create the table, I used UNIQUE(phone), and it doesn't work.

And to add a new contact I am using this code:

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("name", contact.getName()); // get title 
values.put("phone", contact.getNumero()); // get author
// 3. insert
db.insert("contacts", // table
        null, //nullColumnHack
        values);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way of doing that without retrieving the row first. You query the database looking for that particular contact (which you have to specify at least one column to be unique, or any combination of columns to be primary key) otherwise how would you handle two person with the same name?.

So you query and search for the desired person, if you find it, check if the column is null and a) insert if it is, b) ignore if it isn't. If the query doesn't find any person, you cant just insert.

About the unique constraint, its like this:

```
 String CREATETABLE = "CREATE TABLE contacts ( " +
       "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
       "name TEXT, " +
       "phone TEXT UNIQUE)";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample you are using [`SQLiteDatabase.insert()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29), try to use [`SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int%29) with one of values [`CONFLICT_IGNORE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#CONFLICT_IGNORE), [`CONFLICT_REPLACE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#CONFLICT_REPLACE) or others.

Also have a look about implementing database as [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) which is much harder to understand but really good to know.